# Inheriting RLMObject

Tags: realm

Just a quick question on creating realm objects that inherit from each other.

```
@interface BaseObject : RLMObject
@property long commonProp1;
@property long commonProp2;
@property long commonProp3;
@end

@interface InheritingObject : BaseObject
@property NSString *name;
@end

@interface SecondInheritingObject : BaseObject
@property NSString *name2;
@end
```

So the BaseObject has some properties that each InheritingObject inherits. The two inheriting classes are the only ones I want to appear in the database.

Is there any nice way to avoid the BaseObject appearing in the Realm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the class method `+[RLMObject shouldIncludeInDefaultSchema]` on your `BaseObject` and return false, while you would need to overwrite the same method in all your subclasses again to return true, so that they are not excluded by the inherited overridden method.

From [Realm's source](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/v0.98.6/Realm/RLMObjectBase.h#L37-L38):

```
// Returns whether the class is included in the default set of classes persisted in a Realm.

+ (BOOL)shouldIncludeInDefaultSchema;
```